# Entity Framework Include with multiple Select

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Here's an example of what I'm trying to accomplish with Entity Framework. Is there any way of accomplishing this?

```
//This throws an exception because I'm including Items1 twice. But I need both Lists for each Item1
context.MainItems.Include(x=>x.Item1s.Select(y=>y.SubItems1.Select(z=>z.SubSubItem)))
                 .Include(x=>x.Item1s.Select(y=>y.SubItems2))
```

Comment: What is the exact description of the exception?

Comment: The message of the exception is "APPLY joins are not supported". The exception is a "System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandCompilationException". I don't know if that helps.

Comment: Ran into this problem, too. Are you also using SQLite? Did you find a solution?

Comment: I was using SQLite and after reading through their documentation I discovered this a limitation in their Entity Framework Connector. I haven't looked at this for a while though, so they may have upgraded it since then.