# Including multiple many-to-many collection navigation properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, system.data.sqlite

## Description

When attempting to eagerly `.Include()` Many-to-Many `ICollection` properties on an already nested `ICollection`, I receive a `EntityCommandCompilationException` with the `innerException`: `System.NotSupportedException: APPLY joins are not supported.`

- Are there any (suitable) workarounds, or is this simply not supported by EF6/SQLite? If not supported, would migrating to EntityFramework.Core work?
- If some of you can confirm that this is a limitation, I'd create an issue on the SQLite issue tracker

### Quick Problem Synopsis

```csharp
// Bare minimum model definitions - see below for a full implementation

public class Mode
{
    [Key] public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class Type
{
    [Key] public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class Preset
{
    [Key] public string PresetId { get; set; }

    /* Note: Both Types and Modes are Many-To-Many Entity Relationship configured
     * using Join Table/Fluent API */
    public ICollection<Type> Types { get; set; } = new List<Type>();
    public ICollection<Mode> Modes { get; set; } = new List<Mode>();
}

public class Plugin
{
    [Key] public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Preset> Presets { get; set; } = new List<Preset>();
}

public void test ()
{
    context.Plugins
        .Include("Presets.Modes")
        .Include("Presets.Types")
        .Load();
}

// EntityCommandCompilationException An error occurred while preparing the command definition. See the inner exception for details.
// innerException System.NotSupportedException: APPLY joins are not supported
```

This is the basic code which fails. See below for the complete code and how the models are implemented.

In contrast, including just *one* of the two `ICollection` navigation properties works fine:

```csharp
context.Plugins
    .Include("Presets.Modes")
    .Load();
```

Also, including more than one `ICollection` on the same level works fine:

```csharp
context.Presets
    .Include("Modes")
    .Include("Types")
    .Load();
```

## Further Information, Environment

- The problem only affects [EntityFramework6](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework)
  together with [System.Data.SQLite.EF6](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.SQLite.EF6/). As far as I know [EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact) is not affected.
- I am using EF6 Code-First, I have not tried EF6 Model-First or Database-First (and switching to either of those is not an applicable solution)
- The problem only occurs with many-to-many collection navigation properties, and only if I attempt to load multiple ones on the same level
- I have tried common alternatives, including Select(), which yields the same exception
- I have not tried building manual joins or queries, as this would result in extreme code maintenance loss in my project
- At this point, I believe the root cause is a limitation of the SQLite EF6 implementation (which doesn't seem to be documented) rather than something I could fix easily with code
- I've only found one similar [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24376997/entity-framework-include-with-multiple-select) regarding multiple `.Include()`, and the (awful to use) SQLite bugtracker as well as the mailing lists don't seem to mention this particular issue
- The full source code, including a test database with test data can be found in my [GitHub EntityFrameworkResearch repository](https://github.com/Drachenkaetzchen/EntityFrameworkResearch). Specifically the [Model definitions](https://github.com/Drachenkaetzchen/EntityFrameworkResearch/blob/master/src/EntityFrameworkResearch/Models/Ef6.cs), the [DbContext](https://github.com/Drachenkaetzchen/EntityFrameworkResearch/blob/master/src/EntityFrameworkResearch/DbContext/Ef6.cs) and the [repro code](https://github.com/Drachenkaetzchen/EntityFrameworkResearch/blob/master/src/NestedManyToManyIncludeSample/Program.cs)

## Code Reference

```csharp
public class Mode
{
    [Key] public int Id { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Plugin> Plugins { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Preset> Presets { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Type
{
    [Key] public int Id { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Plugin> Plugins { get; set; } = new List<Plugin>();
    public ICollection<Preset> Presets { get; set; } = new List<Preset>();

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string SubTypeName { get; set; }
}

public class Plugin
{
    [Key] public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Preset> Presets { get; set; } = new List<Preset>();

    public ICollection<Type> DefaultTypes { get; set; } = new List<Type>();
    public ICollection<Mode> DefaultModes { get; set; } = new List<Mode>();
}

public class Preset
{
    [Key] public string PresetId { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

    [ForeignKey("Plugin")] public int PluginId { get; set; }

    public Plugin Plugin { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Type> Types { get; set; } = new List<Type>();
    public ICollection<Mode> Modes { get; set; } = new List<Mode>();
}

public class ApplicationDatabaseContext : DbContext
{
    // Constructor and further database initialization omitted for clarity

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

        modelBuilder.Entity<Plugin>()
            .HasMany(p => p.DefaultModes)
            .WithMany(q => q.Plugins)
            .Map(mc => mc.MapLeftKey("PluginId").MapRightKey("ModeId").ToTable("PluginModes"));

        modelBuilder.Entity<Plugin>()
            .HasMany(p => p.DefaultTypes)
            .WithMany(q => q.Plugins)
            .Map(mc => mc.MapLeftKey("PluginId").MapRightKey("TypeId").ToTable("PluginTypes"));


        modelBuilder.Entity<Preset>()
            .HasMany(p => p.Types)
            .WithMany(q => q.Presets)
            .Map(mc =>mc.MapLeftKey("PresetId").MapRightKey("TypeId").ToTable("PresetTypes"));

        modelBuilder.Entity<Preset>()
            .HasMany(p => p.Modes)
            .WithMany(q => q.Presets)
            .Map(mc => mc.MapLeftKey("PresetId").MapRightKey("ModeId").ToTable("PresetModes"));
    }

    public DbSet<Plugin> Plugins { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Preset> Presets { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Mode> Modes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Type> Types { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: No, it does not clearly indicate the limitation or problem, especially if one many-to-many Include works, and two aren't. Why do you think that SQLite should - or should not - create an APPLY join? The point of EF6 is to abstract away the internals. Also, why do you think that a developer should know about EF6 internals? I'm sorry, but your comment is clearly a comment from hell, providing neither a solution, clear answer nor a benefit to the original question.

Comment: Now it's more clear ;) I try to be as clear as possible in my questions, providing a value for both affected parties as well as readers (in fact, it took me almost 4 hours to prepare the issue, stripping down the production system into a simple as possible testcase, researching the interwebz(tm)) so I sometimes get easily frustrated with ambiguous answers. I hope you don't feel offended ;)

Comment: No, I'm not looking for official confirmation, if so I would have used the official mailing lists or issue tracker. Right now, my question is in a "is this a bug? is this a quirk? is this an oversight on my side? is there an easy fix?" status.

I did not test against SqlServer, but during my research I have found (similar) looking questions which seemed to work. Again - "similar looking", judging from often incomplete code pasted into StackOverflow questions :(

Also, I'm extremely new to C# (<6 months) and to EF6 (<1 month) so chances are that I did miss something completely obvious.

Comment: Ok, note taken! :) If you don't mind, let remove the comments then. Good luck!

Comment: I hit the same error, when using Include over a child collection that was also using inheritance.  Gave up after a few hours, and replaced Include with Load() calls for each inherited type.